# Is it right to say when no options are selected from menu in a form, neither name or value passed to the server

Tags: php, forms

I am doing PHP validation, and I was reading [w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#menu) on forms. Can anyone clarify this statement
"When no options are selected, the control is not successful and neither the name nor any values are submitted to the server when the form is submitted". To test this, I have created

```
<form method="get" action="#">
    <select name="select_name" >
       <option value="">Select one</option>
      <option value="one">Choice one</option>
       <option value="two" >Choice two</option>
       <option value="three">Choice three</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

When I print the GET array, I see that the name "select_name" always passed to the server. For radio and checkbox, this is not true. But I do not understand what that statement trying to say. Is it possible for "neither name nor value" to be passed during select option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The specification you quoted:

> *When no options are selected, the control is not successful and neither the name nor any values are submitted to the server when the form is submitted.*

...indicates what to do when *no options are selected*, but by default most browsers will automatically select the first option of a (drop-down) select element. Do you not see on your test page that the first option "Select one" is automatically selected when the page loads? In your case where the first option has an empty string as its value if you then submitted the form with that option selected you should have a request parameter with the name "select_name" and a value that is an empty string.

In the case of a (non-drop-down) select multiple element:

```
<select name="select_name" multiple>
```

...no option is selected by default so then if you submit without selecting any options you should see that you don't get a "select_name" request parameter.

NOTE: You tagged your question with "PHP", but this is not a PHP thing. It's the browser that forms the request according to the state of the form controls at the time.

Comment: So the earlier words I quoted from w3.org is referring to the case you mentioned, if "multiple" is set? I tried what you just said, and true nothing is passed over. If I add one more question, for "radio" and "checkbox" also depending on the browser a default is set?

Comment: Radio buttons and checkboxes both default to unchecked (and thus wouldn't be submitted). It's reasonably normal to code radio buttons so that one is checked by default, but if you don't do so in your markup the browser won't do it.

Comment: With drop-down select lists, the only way I know of to have no option selected is to set `.selectedIndex = -1` through JavaScript. I would assume if you did that you would have no "select_name" parameter in the request, but I've not tried it.